# Elasticsearch - search if tags contains values in a list

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Is it possible to query for records where 2 different tags have values in a specified list?

`matches_list = ["4000000031265595", "4000000031265596", "4000000030004305", "4000000029975772"]`

```
query = {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match":  {"id_1": matches_list}},
        {"match":  {"id_2": matches_list}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above returns:
`elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, u'illegal_state_exception', u"Can't get text on a START_ARRAY at 1:57")`

*Update*

Error when using large list:

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 128, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 122, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'failed to create query: {\n  "bool" : {\n    "must" : [\n      {\n        "terms" : {\n          "id_1" : my list in here  ],\n          "boost" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    "disable_coord" : false,\n    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,\n    "boost" : 1.0\n  }\n}')`

Comment: what are the types of `id_1` and `id_2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `match` query doesn't work with arrays but with a single string input. Use `terms` instead:

```
query = {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"terms":  {"id_1": matches_list}},
        {"terms":  {"id_2": matches_list}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @val. Is there a limit to the size of this list? Anything over a length of 100 seems to fail

Comment: Thanks again Val. I've added it to the question to make it readable. It's not a very good error to be honest. I know ES defaults to 10 results, so I'll maybe change this part to see if it impacts on this further downstream

Comment: That's the error you get on Python's side, I'm interested in the one you see in the ES logs.

Comment: Usually in `/var/log/elasticsearch` or if you have a local install, it's in `ES_HOME/logs`

Comment: Got it! `Caused by: org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024`

Comment: Try to use `filter` instead of `must`, it might be all that's needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    {      
      "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                   {"bool": {
                    "should": [
                       {"match":  {"id_1": "4000000031265595"}},
                       {"match":  {"id_1": "4000000031265596"}}
                    ]
                   }},
                   {"bool": {
                    "should": [
                       {"match":  {"id_2": "4000000031265595"}},
                       {"match":  {"id_2": "4000000031265596"}}
                    ]
                   }}

                ]

            }
        }


    }
```